# SOQL Statement Results based on Subquery

Tags: soql

I need help with this SOQL statement.  I need it to return results from Account object based on a subquery.  What I have below doesn't work.  The objects are 1:1 relationship.  There is an External ID on Business__c and Account object.

Thanks,

SELECT ID, Combine__c
FROM Account
WHERE Combine__c IN
( SELECT ID, Combine__c
FROM Business__c
)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but that will not work.  Error Message: The left operand field in the where expression for outer query should be an id field, cannot use: 'Combine__c'.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I think the problem is I don't have a relationship established between the two objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to split it into to SOQL queries or add a relationship field.

```
Set<string> combineIds = new Set<string>();
for(Business__c bus : [Select Combine__c from Business__c]) {
    combineIds.add(bus.Combine__c);
}
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT ID, Combine__c FROM Account WHERE Combine__c IN :combineIds];
```